# Auto width drop down menu conbine with input text

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input text combined with a drop down menu of Bootstrap. I used input-prepend as the following code:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
<div class="btn-group">
    <button id="btn-cat" class="btn" tabindex="-1" name="category">All</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1"> <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="category-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Computers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cell Phones & Accessories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Magazine Subscriptions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Video Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sports & Outdoors</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type="text">
```

Please refer to a demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LCdvQ/1/

The problem is when I select a long menu item, input text will be moved to the right. What I want is an effect like the search box at amazon.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U want something like this..??

http://jsfiddle.net/LCdvQ/4/

```
.input-prepend{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 500px;
}

.text1{
    border: 0px!important;
}
```